# Repeater itemAt() returns null

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to put 4 TextFields underneath 4 sliders and modify those sliders. However, when i try to access the sliders with itemAt(), the return value is null. In addition to that, I'm not sure how to get the TextFields underneath the sliders as they are positioned next to the sliders.

```
Row{
        spacing: 40

        anchors{
            top: parent.top
            bottom: parent.bottom
            bottomMargin: 70
            topMargin: 70
            leftMargin: 20
        }

        Repeater{
            id: slidersRepeater
            model: 4
            Slider{
                ...
            }
        }

        Repeater{
            model: 4
            TextField{
                property string sliderValue: slidersRepeater.itemAt(index).value.toString()
                text: sliderValue
                
                anchors{
                    top: slidersRepeater.bottom
                    topMargin: 30
                }
                
                width: 30
                height: 15
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's better to do this backward, like: `onValueChanged: fieldsRepeater.itemAt(index).text = value`. Also, avoid using anchors inside `Row`'s children.

Comment: Currently, you are receiving this error because your sliders have not been instantiated yet. And even if you use the nullish operator to work around this error, it will not be able to create a binding and nothing will happen.

Comment: @smr Your suggestion worked out for me, but I would like to ask why Slider was not instantiated? Shouldn't Slider already be instantiated by the time TextField is created since it was created before?

Comment: The fact that it appears before in the code does not imply that it was created before, the asynchrony of the repeaters means that the objects are created when they are necessary.

Comment: My recommendation is to use a ListModel for both repeaters and bind the properties

Answer (score 0):

If for each Slider and for each TextField you add the following code

```
Component.onCompleted: console.log(`Slider ${index}`);
Component.onCompleted: console.log(`TextField ${index}`);
```

You quickly realize you are not in the control of the order of your delegates. And, in fact, you should write your code to work so that it works regardless of delegate order.

For instance:

```
ListModel { id: m }
Repeater { model: m }
Repeater { model: m }
```

You can create two Repeaters hooked up to the same ListModel this is more likely to work for you.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ListModel {
        id: m
        Component.onCompleted: {
            append({v:0.2});
            append({v:0.4});
            append({v:0.6});
            append({v:0.8});
        }
    }
    Column {
        Repeater {
            model: m
            Slider {
                value: v
                onValueChanged: v = value
            }
        }
        Repeater {
            model: m
            TextField {
                text: v
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACDXiclZBLC8IwEITv+RU56qWIiEjFU8CTglXxHsxSg3mUdhuEkv9ug2JfWnAOYYdvSGYjdWZzpAkmpbzeiezYiFmDuVUFOfAUaEVorZ0scG8FqLcPkiKm+uOYrW8xYDCyJswKEOpAEw/iWQZGTCoXz6K5n65/wsUYXI7BVRt60pzMqlKbVqEjZMAR8l5HHdZsbxZ0UlIMkkGOqxJi6gbAmktA7MZNGj7C0c0r3El6Mpz+6XWGB24lKPGlGtas36z/nif+CXUMfWQ=)

Say, for example, the program starts up:

1. Initially ListModel is empty, therefore no delegates are created
2. When one record appears in the ListModel, one TextField and one Slider is created afterwards.
3. Hence the data must exist in the ListModel first
4. The creation order of TextField and Slider is not important, since either will not error out and they will always see a valid ListModel entry
5. Same as other data is populated